# Excel VBA: Object not set in second loop

Tags: vba, excel

In the second iteration of a loop, VBA crashes setting `TestRange`, which is dependent on another range `CurrentDataTop`, saying "object required...".

I set `CurrentDataTop` at the start of each loop, and the first iteration runs through OK.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AMystery()

Dim OutBook As Workbook, MasterWorkbook As Workbook
Dim CurrentDataTop As Range, CurrentData As Range, TestRange As Range
Dim Index As Double, i As Double, iTop As Double, iBottom As Double, iColumn As Double

Set MasterWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

'MainLoopStart
For Index = 1 To 3

    MasterWorkbook.Sheets.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=MasterWorkbook.Path & "\NewName_" & Index & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
    Set OutBook = Workbooks("NewName_" & Index & ".xlsx")
    OutBook.Activate

    ' Set new range starts, within the duplicate book
    Set CurrentDataTop = OutBook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("E6")

        'Delete some data not required
            CurrentDataTop.Worksheet.Activate
            iTop = CurrentDataTop.Row
            iColumn = CurrentDataTop.Column
            iBottom = Cells(Rows.Count, CurrentDataTop.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = iBottom To iTop Step -1
                If Cells(i, iColumn).Value <> Index Then
                    Rows(i).Delete
                End If
            Next i

        'IT CRASHES HERE ON THE SECOND LOOP, SAYING "OBJECT REQUIRED"
        Set TestRange = CurrentDataTop.Offset(0, 10)
        TestRange.Value = "Some text"

        'Save & close new book
        OutBook.Save
        OutBook.Close

'MainLoopEnd
Next Index

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cell E6 in the original workbook probably contained a value of 1.

Therefore, on the second iteration, your code will delete the row containing `CurrentDataTop` (i.e. cell E6) because the cell does not contain a 2.

When you go to `Offset` from a non-existent cell, the code will crash as `Offset` can only be performed if there is an object to offset from.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I was being a muppet there, but you saved the day.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are deleted all of `CurrentDataTop`'s cells.

[image]

Comment: Thanks also for this recording - very useful :)

Comment: Thanks, I/m glad that you liked it. I started trying to show debugging techniques.